# `audit.conf` man page is missing

Tags: manpage

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 latest version, and when I do `man audit.conf` it returns `No manual entry for audit.conf` but I need it...

Comment: Or are you looking for: man libaudit.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for `man auditd.conf`, not `man audit.conf`?

In a comment, you say

```
man auditd.conf
```

also prints `No manual entry for auditd.conf`, right?
That means, the package that contains it is not installed;

It's easy to guess, but let's find which package we need systematically:

```
$ apt-file search auditd.conf
auditd: /etc/audit/auditd.conf
auditd: /usr/share/man/man5/auditd.conf.5.gz
```

So, the package `auditd` contains the file `auditd.conf` - and the man page for it.
Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install auditd
```

Now,

```
man auditd.conf
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [auditd.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/auditd.conf.5.html)? Try `man auditd.conf`...

If, per your comment, that also gives you an error, then you need to install the package first, see Volker's answer.

Comment: I tried auditd.conf ahgain it returns the same result there is no folder named audit inside /etc